# Passing usetranslation as a parameter to function from jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs

I wanted to pass use-translation as a parameter to util function I created, I'm not able get the desired result, how can I pass a function?

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

import { submissionTypes } from "../../Submissions/Details/constants";

import { getFormName } from "./helpers";

// jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
//     useTranslation: () => ({ t: key => key }),
// }));

// jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
//     useTranslation: () => ({
//         i18n: { changeLanguage: jest.fn() },
//         t: key => key,
//     }),
//   }));

describe("utils/helpers", () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    describe("getFormName()", () => {
      it("should return withdrawal", () => {
        const result = getFormName("withdrawal", true, t ); //last parameter is 't' which is a translation function 
        expect(result).toEqual("WITHDRAWAL");
      });
    });
  });
```

---

Below if function definiton for getFormName:

```
export function getFormName(type, uppercase, t) {
  switch (type) {
    case "withdrawal":
      return uppercase
        ? _.upperCase(t("mission.withdrawal"))
        : t("mission.withdrawal");
    default:
      return uppercase ? _.upperCase(type) : toTitleCase(type);
  }
}
```

Comment: useTranslation is a hook

Comment: @adrai I'm new to Jest testing, can you help me know how can I do it?

Comment: https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/test-jest

Comment: @adrai I have added definition for getFormName function, it accepts "t" translation function